# Why does running a delete and create command in one statement with kubectl cause Service connection failure?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-service

Here is my service.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: secondapp
  labels:
    run: my-nginx
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    example: second
  ports:
    - port: 80
      protocol: TCP
      nodePort: 32000
```

When using kubectl to delete and re-create the service from a yaml file in one statement, the service (NodePort) refuses connections. E.g.

```
student@master:~/app2$ kubectl delete svc secondapp ; kubectl create -f service.yaml
service "secondapp" deleted
service/secondapp created

student@master:~/app2$ k get svc secondapp
NAME        TYPE       CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
secondapp   NodePort   10.111.119.42   <none>        80:32000/TCP   10s
student@master:~/app2$ curl 10.111.119.42
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.111.119.42 port 80: Connection refused
```

If I then simply break the commands apart into two separate statements, it works as follows:

```
student@master:~/app2$ kubectl delete svc secondapp
service "secondapp" deleted
student@master:~/app2$ kubectl create -f service.yaml
service/secondapp created
student@master:~/app2$ k get svc secondapp
NAME        TYPE       CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
secondapp   NodePort   10.99.157.101   <none>        80:32000/TCP   8s
student@master:~/app2$ curl 10.99.157.101
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
<style>
    body {
        width: 35em;
        margin: 0 auto;
        font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to nginx!</h1>
<p>If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and
working. Further configuration is required.</p>

<p>For online documentation and support please refer to
<a href="http://nginx.org/">nginx.org</a>.<br/>
Commercial support is available at
<a href="http://nginx.com/">nginx.com</a>.</p>

<p><em>Thank you for using nginx.</em></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Why does running the commands on one line break the service, even though it all looks fine ?

Note that I am running the above on Google Cloud Compute Engine.

Comment: could just be timing issue, what if you run `kubectl describe service` to see if it has the valid endpoints?

Comment: Yes, I have described the service and it does have valid endpoints. Everything looks like it "should" work.

Comment: To access ClusterIP service use $ kubectl exec -it pod-name -- sh command and then use curl command: $ curl cluster-ip:80

Comment: Did my comment help ?

Comment: Thanks, but no unfortunately it didn't. My service was a NodePort and should be accessible from outside the cluster. If you re-read the problem, you'll see that it works fine under one scenario, and under the other it does not. My question is why the two scenarios even make a difference.
I am of the opinion it must be a timing issue as mentioned in the first comment.

Comment: Does this problem still exist ? If you want to access it from outside the cluster connect on  `http://<node-ip>: 332000` and try this when problem with connecting within the cluster will exists if check if connection from outside the cluster will also be interrupted. Maybe cluster network connection then was broken.